# Вопросы по ООП в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, деструктор

Изучаю базу питона по книге bite of python.

Случилась неувязка в голове которую не могу никак объяснить, а именно:

После объявления класса идёт метод инициализации, а далее идёт метод  `__del__` со своим алгоритмом вывода текста и воздействием на переменную класса.

В конце объявляю новую переменную droid1 в которой храниться класс?
Вот тут начинаются вопросы.

1. Каким образом "Помещая" класс в переменную он автоматически запускается??
   Я думал переменная просто хранит определенный объект со значением, а тут оказывается что он просто запустился из переменной..
2. В любом случае на выводе я получил три строки. Первая ясно что из метода инициализации класса. Но вторая, каким образом метод `__del__` сработал, а почему методы SayHi() и HiMany() в этом случае не сработали тогда?? Почему именно два первых?

Если в процедурном программировании алгоритм выполнения строго определён и понятен мне, то здесь я не понимаю в каком порядке выполняется алгоритм.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Robot:    # Создание класса

    population = 0  # Переменная класса, содержащая колличество роботов

    def __init__(self, name):   # Метод инициализации

        self.name = name    # Введенная переменная с условным методом self
        print('Инициализация {0}'.format(self.name)) 
        Robot.population += 1

    def __del__(self):
        print('Робот {} уничтожен'.format(self.name))
        Robot.population -= 1

        if Robot.population == 0:
            print('Больше роботов не осталось. Робот {0} был последним'.format(self.name))
        else:
    
            print('Осталось {0:d} работающих роботов.'.format(Robot.population))

    def SayHi(self):
        print('Имя данное мне {0}'.format(self.name))

    def HowMany():
        print('На данный момент у нас {} роботов'.format(Robot.population))

droid1 = Robot('R2-D2')
```

Comment: Вы создали экземпляр класса - значит вызвали метод `__init__`. Вы уничтожили его, завершив работу программы - значит вызвали метод `__del__`. Методы `SayHi` и `HowMany` нигде никак не вызывались. Всё просто

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Класс не запускается. При создании объекта класса выполняется метод `__init__()`. Она и печатает первую строку.
2. Метод `__del__()` срабатывает, когда удаляется объект класса. Вы запускали код в IDE (возможно, PyCharm), она подчистила за собой память и удалила `droid1`. Если вы запустите свой код в IDLE (простенький редактор, который идет вместе с дистрибутивом питона), то метод `__del__()` не будет вызван и выведется только строчка с инициализацией.

Методы `SayHi()` и `HowMany()` никто не вызывал, потому они не выполнялись.

---

Интересно будет, если вы добавите строчку :)

```
droid2 = Robot("HAL")
```

> Инициализация R2-D2

> Инициализация HAL

> Робот R2-D2 уничтожен

> Осталось 1 работающих роботов.

> Робот HAL уничтожен

> Больше роботов не осталось. Робот HAL был последним

Answer (score 1):

Он не 'запускается'. А создаётся обьект класса Robot, запуская конструктор`__init__` и присваивается в переменную. А когда программа завершается - python начинает уборку мусора и уничтожает обьект, запуская деструктор `__del__.` Поэтому ты и наблюдаешь такой вывод.